# Global image threshold in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

When you use graythresh in Matlab it obtains a value that is a normalized between 0 to 1, so when you use a threshold for something else such as imextendedmax or im2bw how would you use graythresh? I guess you have to probably multiply it by something but what?

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalize your image to [0...1] in order to use `graythresh`.

```
%# test image
img = randn(512);
img(200:end,100:end) = img(200:end,100:end) + 5;

%# normalize. Subtract minimum to make lowest intensity equal to 0, then divide by the maximum
offset = min(img(:));
img = img - offset;
mult = max(img(:));
img = img./mult;

%# apply graythresh
th = graythresh(img);

%# if you want to know the threshold relative to the original intensities, use mult and offset like this
oriThresh = th*mult+offset;
```

Comment: you can normalize in only one line using `img = (img - min(img(:))) / (max(img(:)) - min(img(:)))`

Comment: @BlackAdder: Indeed you can. Capturing the offset and the multiplier helps you to revert your threshold back to original units, which is important if you want to segment multiple images with the same threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Either normalize your image to range between 0 and 1, or multiply the threshold by the maximum possible value of the image.